# ¿Cómo acceder a un objeto ya existente en php?

Tags: php, mvc, poo, php7

Hola lo que pasa es que trato de actualizar un cliente en mi aplicación. En una tabla que me muestra los clientes mediante el icono editar lo reenvío a otra pagina que se llama vista/actualizaCliente.php Luego en los input de enviarlos al archivo controlador/actualiza-cliente.php y trato de hacer lo siguiente pero me da error.

```
 <?php

session_start();
require_once("../Modelo/conexionBaseDatos.php");
//require_once("../Modelo/cliente.php");


?>



<?php


if (isset($_POST['actualizaCliente'])) {

    include "../Modelo/cliente.php";

    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";

    $obj=new Cliente();

    $actualizar=$obj->actualizaCliente($_POST['codigo']);


}

?>
```

Me aparece el error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Cliente::actualizaCliente() in C:\wamp64\www\VentaSystem3\Controlador\actualizar-cliente.php on line 25. Por lo tanto lo que quiero es acceder a un objeto que ya existe. Alguien ,e puede dar una mano?

Comment: Dice que el metodo no esta definido.  Deberias agregar el metodo en cuestion.

Comment: alanfcm Es que el método ya lo definí en un fichero donde cree una clase cliente. Lo que quiero es acceder a esa clase para poder crear una instancia de esa clase en el fichero actual. Estoy tratando con use pero no me da.

Comment: Pon el código de `cliente.php` para ver como se ha creado el método `actualizaCliente`. Porque como dice @alanfcm no encuentra el método. Revisa que esté bien escrito el nombre del método.